# How to add text to form input

Tags: javascript, html

I am really not sure where to start with this. I have a form input box and submit button. When the submit button is pressed, the form content is submitted and used in some javascript. What I want to do is automatically add some text to the end of the submission.

So if a user inputs "The dog walked" and pressed submit, the form would add "across the street." to the end of the submission.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 10):

In your event listener for the form's submit action, change the input.

```
document.getElementById('theinputid').value = document.getElementById('theinputid').value + "across the street."
```

Answer (score 7):

W3 schools is your friend: [Form onsubmit Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)
So in your case it's something similar to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addText() {
        var input = document.getElementById('something');
        input.value = input.value +' across the street';
    }
</script>

<form name="frm1" action="?" onsubmit="addText()">
    <input type="text" name="somehting" id="something" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use `+=`, for instance:

```
input.value +=
```