# Making get/post requests to bootstrap modals. How?

Tags: javascript, http, request, modal-dialog

I am having a really difficult time trying to make a request and communicate with modals from other websites. For regular html you can see the hyperlink when hovering over the link or find out all about the element when inspecting, but with modals it seems like all the code is hidden on their website somewhere, making me unable to send http get/post requests correctly.

For ex when theres a button called "View containers" it opens up a modal and then theres a textarea field and a submit button. I know the ID of the text field, but there is like zero information on the submit button or where the submit button can lead to. I want to make a script that **automatically sends a request , enter in the container # and clicks submit**. But I dont know how to **make the script click/send submit button**

Comment: once the modal is visible, it's just like any other element and can inspected and manipulated at will

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd want to [change the input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714564/how-to-add-text-to-form-input)

You can click buttons using the [DOM click method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) after selecting it, [probably using IDs](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_id.asp)

Additionally, I'd ensure the modal was put into the DOM before trying to insert values, or press submit...modals may not be inserted to the DOM until they are triggered/loaded.